# how to dispplay facebook in webview instead of Fbdialog through Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to use Facebook SDK in Android but don't want this on any Dialog(fbDialog), I want facebook login on Webview but I am unable to do that. Please any one can tell me how can this issue be resolved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can't do that. Try fbRocket a third party api for facebook android, it will fulfill your requirement.